# RowExpander doesn’t work correctly in IE11 in the grid

Tags: gwt, gxt

I used `GXT 3.1.0` and `GWT 2.6.0`. `RowExpander` doesn’t work correctly in `IE11` in the grid. By the attempt to collapse row in the grid the error is following (you can follow the [link](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:rowexpandergrid) and check for yourself):
[image: RowExpander problem]

The `RowExpander` position is collapsed in first line, but content is visible.

The grid with grouping of the same column has the similar problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?